# Mac protected from easy burn stuff

Tags: mac, keyboard, security

This is not fun or anything like that. Imagine. You're constantly using your Mac to watch Netflix or similar while eating popcorn or whatever.

The crumbs would be able to if they got into the ventilation ducts or through the keyboard. Could these pose a threat to the Mac? On my Mac there are often high temperatures, which I read out. Or are the processors sufficiently isolated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're worrying unnecessarily.
Sure, it's not good to get crumbs in the keyboard - it can lead to keys not working as they should.

However, household dust is just as inflammable as popcorn… & when was the last time you heard of a dusty old computer actually catching fire?
As it fills up with dust bunny, it will throttle itself slower & slower to keep the temperature down.

Critical temperature for most computer processors is about 100°C. That's hot enough to boil water, but not hot enough to set anything on fire.
You would need a significant hardware fail for fire to actually be a hazard.

Comment: But 100 degrees. Some processors reach 105 degrees at Apple. These could already produce light smoke. But do these crumbs get anywhere near the processor or is it well protected?

Comment: "could already produce light smoke" - where are you getting this data from?  Popcorn doesn't even start popping below about 175°C. An air popper runs at about 190°.

Comment: Oh thanks @tetsuijn my bro. But isn't it different with dust?

Comment: https://www.tayloredge.com/reference/Science/ignition.html They don't cover 'dust' but consider wood/paper/dust etc. Everyone knows that paper burns at 451°F

Comment: Thanks man you really took my fear away. Really thank you